# 2017 MBP has started to degrade in performance - dreaded kernel_task

Tags: macos, performance, temperature, firefox, kernel

All -
My normally stable mbp 2017 has started slowing down with kernel_thread dominating the CPU in recent weeks. This condition persists across reboots. My primary concern is that the machine is overheating (please see troubleshooting to date).

Any ideas?  The wildest idea I have at the moment is that Firefox had some sort of deep JS hack; Zoom has rolled out crappier code in 5.X series (nothing to do with heat); and the thermal throttling is normal.

Are there any alternative troubleshooting steps I can take short of returning my mac for service? I don't have a backup and really can't be without a computer for 5+ days for work. I've also thought about buying a new machine but Apple pricing is just spectacular.

Things  I've tried:

- Restarting the machine
- Restarting / running diags (nothing found)
- Re-installing key apps
- Air-blowing out the exhaust ports

Symptoms:

- Until I re-installed Firefox (user profiles *preserved*) - connecting MBP to the internet would result in immediate spike in kernel_threads
- Zoom meetings also trigger the

Data I've been using:

- iStats Menu for detailed graphs
- pmset -g thermal

Observations:

- No observable memory pressure
- Temperatures on thunderbolt port, cpu etc seem nominal but pmset is showing thermal throttling

This has triggered a conversation about refreshing to a MBP 2016 or macmini,  but its an awfully expensive "fix" if there are other ways to root cause the behaviour.

Comment: Do you have anything plugged in to the Thunderbolt ports? - Have you tried connecting the charger cable on the other side of the MacBook Pro (if the charger is plugged in at all)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I will update the Op.  I have two monitors on the right, one supplying power and then the main network/usb hub- (also powered :-/ ) on the left.  According to istat - Temperatures do not seem crazy...

Comment: So what happens if you disconnect those peripherals? - Does the problem go away?

Comment: Apologies for my delayed response. I somehow missed the battery swelling to silly-town size which had split the right side of the bottom case right open... so everything went down hill from there.